# Python 3.7: How to install chromaprint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda, python-3.7

I am currently trying to work with pyacoustid and it requires the installation of chromaprint and I get this error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-05787a729ee6> in <module>
         1 import acoustid
   ----> 2 import chromaprint

 ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\chromaprint.py in <module>
         55         break
         56 else:
    ---> 57     raise ImportError("couldn't find libchromaprint")
         58 
         59 

ImportError: couldn't find libchromaprint
```

Comment: May I please ask for assistance. It was so difficult trying to format the question. That I forgot my manners

Comment: Have you gone through building the lib? https://github.com/acoustid/chromaprint

Comment: @Pipetus yes we have followed the process on the github.com/acoustid/chromaprint link. Following the steps outlined in the link results in the error zimotanks is getting. Could it relate to us making use of Anaconda instead of the base version of Python 3.7?

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? _Could it relate to us making use of Anaconda instead of the base version of Python 3.7?_ The error traceback seems to be referencing the system's Python installation, no?

Comment: We're using Python 3.7.3 [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Comment: @zimotanks I see. The error clearly states that it cannot find the lib. Does it exist in you system after the build is done? What about the path? How does Python look for it?